# Getting the number of Spiderfiable markers with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier in my project.
I would like to show the number of elements under a spiderfiable marker, just like a cluster from Google Maps API.

The code I've implemented looks like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_format', function(status) {   

        if(status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIED 
|| status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.UNSPIDERFIABLE)

        {
            marker.setIcon('Markers/marker.png'); 
//use a regular marker if the element is already spiderfied or if it can not be spiderfied
        }

        if(status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE)

        {
            marker.setIcon('Markers/cluster_marker.png'); //use a cluster marker
            // get the number of elements under the cluster....
            // show the number of elements under the cluster....
        }           
    });
```

Is there a way to get the number of elements to be spiderfied under each spiderfiable marker?